# verifying NVIDIA __shared__ memory is used when cache directive is present

Tags: cuda, openacc

I'm experimenting with OpenACC's cache clause using PGI 14.10. I've got a simple loop based on the one in the slides at [1]:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int N = 1024;
    int *restrict x = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * N);
    int *restrict y = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * N);

#pragma acc parallel loop copy(x[0:N], y[0:N])
    for (int i = 1; i < N - 1; i++) {
#pragma acc cache(x[i-1:2])
        y[i] = (x[i - 1] + x[i + 1]) / 2.0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this under nvprof with --metrics shared_load_transactions,shared_store_transactions it reports no loads or stores. So is the cache directive not having the effect I want (and if so why isn't it working)? Or is using nvprof to measure shared transactions incorrect?

Minfo output is below.

[1] http://www.pgroup.com/lit/presentations/cea-3.pdf

```
main:
      6, Generating copy(x[:N])
         Generating copy(y[:N])
         Accelerator kernel generated
          9, #pragma acc loop gang, vector(256) /* blockIdx.x threadIdx.x */
      6, Generating Tesla code
```

Comment: Adding -ta=keepptx,keepgpu shows that no __shared__ memory is being used, so now it's a matter of figuring out why the cache directive is having no effect?

Comment: provide a complete code. SO expects you to provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Are you using the `restrict` keyword anywhere?

Comment: sure, i've updated the original post with a full, working example of cache not working.

Answer (score 3):

Answered on the PGI Forums: http://www.pgroup.com/userforum/viewtopic.php?t=4611&start=0&postdays=0&postorder=asc&highlight=

Apparently, the cache directive was almost entirely disabled on PGI 14.x compilers, but will be available in the 2015 version.